# Python: make all non-combining unicode characters combining

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, python-unicode

I have string with accents and diacritics represented by non combining characters:

```
vyˇcíslitelnost (nerozhodnutelnost, v ˇety o neúplnosti),um ˇelá inteligence (automatické odvozování, rezoluce), univerzální nástroje: SAT a SMT ˇrešiˇce
```

and I want to turn them into combining characters. For example string above will looks like:

```
vyčíslitelnost (nerozhodnutelnost, věty o neúplnosti),umělá inteligence (automatické odvozování, rezoluce), univerzální nástroje: SAT a SMT řešiče
```

How can I achive this ? I already tried `unicodedata.normalize` but it has no effects on non-combining characters.

Thank you for help

Comment: From a comment on my deleted answer: "I want to turn "ˇc" into "č"".

Comment: I do not know a better method, but in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacing_Modifier_Letters you see that non-combining version of combining characters. You may want to map each of them with the combining code (Unicode website has a search function, the names should be very similar, or check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks). For sure there will be other blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my old-school (anti-pythonic) approach:

```
import unicodedata

lettersWithCaron = 'ČčĎďĚěĽľŇňŘřŠšŤťŽžǅǍǎǏǐǑǒǓǔǦǧǨǩǰȞȟ' # from Unicode database
caron            = '\u02C7'

astring = 'vyˇcíslitelnost (nerozhodnutelnost, v ˇety o neúplnosti),um ˇelá inteligence (automatické odvozování, rezoluce), univerzální nástroje: SAT a SMT ˇrešiˇce'
for lett in lettersWithCaron:
    astring = astring.replace(
        (caron + unicodedata.normalize( 'NFD',lett)).replace('\u030C',''), lett)
    
print( astring)
```

**Output** shows that there is an additional space before some carons (`v ˇety`, `um ˇelá`) in your string (unlike in `ˇrešiˇce`)…

```
.\SO\69647976.py
```

> vyčíslitelnost (nerozhodnutelnost, v ěty o neúplnosti),um ělá
> inteligence (automatické odvozování, rezoluce), univerzální nástroje:
> SAT a SMT řešiče